# How to create a array that lets user know they are out-of-bounds?

Tags: c++, arrays, int

I'm trying to create a program that helps a user create an array index starting at any integer. 
It should also notify the user during the execution/accessing the array component that is out-of-bounds.

This is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
class safeArray;
};

const int CAPACITY=5;
```

I have set the capacity of the array to 5 so there can be a limit. Leaving the user to be able to go out of bounds.

```
class safeArray() {
userArray= new int [CAPACITY];
```

The user will be able to create a new int value for each slot in the array.

```
cout <<"Enter any integers for your safe userArray:";

if (int=0;i<CAPACITY;i++) {
    cout<<"You are in-bounds!";
}

else (int=0;i>CAPACITY;i++){
    cout<<"You are OUT-OF-BOUNDS!";
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
};
```

I went with an if-else statement in order to check the array subscript?
I'm new to C++ so any clarification of errors or methods on how to simplify it would be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: You're in luck. C++ already has an array object with bounds checking, it's called `std::vector`, and its `at()` method will throw an exception if the index is out of bounds. It would be a simple matter to subclass it, and overload the `[]` operator to invoke `at()`. Subclassing and operator overloading is not exactly something that someone "new to C++" is likely to have learned, to date. So, keep reading your C++ book, and eventually you're going to get there.

Comment: When you know the size of your array beforehand better use `std::array`, the `std::array::at` method will throw `std::out_of_range` when the index is out of bounds.

Comment: The fixed size std::array<N> also has such bounding check same as using at(). http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - not to be pedantic, but wrapping `std::vector`  would probably be better. Using STL container classes as a base is not recommended as the dtors are not virtual. Personally, I'd just use vanilla `std::vector` for what OP seems to want, but... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements should just read:

```
if (i<CAPACITY && i>0) {
    cout<<"You are in-bounds!";
}

else if (i>CAPACITY){
    cout<<"You are OUT-OF-BOUNDS!";
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
};
```

Also, what happens in the edge case when i == capacity? Your code doesn't handle this case at all.

To make this neater, you could format it with only one if/else statement

```
if (i<CAPACITY && i>0) { // Or should this be (i<=CAPACITY)??? depends on whether 0 is an index or not
    cout<<"You are in-bounds!";
} else {
    cout<<"You are OUT-OF-BOUNDS!";
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: What about negative index values?

Comment: even better solution is to disallow negative numbers entirely with an `unsigned` data type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling memory management you could use a standard container such as  [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for dynamic "arrays" or [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for fixed size arrays.

[std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) has zero overhead on all major compilers and is more or less a C++ wrapper around C arrays.

In order to let the user know when the index is out of bounds most standard containers provide the `at(std::size_t n)` method (e.g. [std::vector::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at)) that do all the rage checking for you and throw a [std::out_of_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception when supplying an invalid index/position.

All you have to do now is catch that exception and print a message if you want to.
Here's a little example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 12> arr;
    try {
        std::cout << arr.at(15) << '\n';
    } catch (std::out_of_range const &) {
        std::cout << "Sorry mate, the index you supplied is out of range!" << '\n';
    }
}
```

[live preview - ideone.com](http://ideone.com/WSJhPh)